# Endpoint for Cloud Function returns 403 Forbidden

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am following Google's [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-cloud-functions) for setting up an Endpoint for my cloud function.

When I try to access the endpoint from my browser using URL `service_name.a.run.app/function1` I get

```
Error: Forbidden
Your client does not have permission to get URL /function1GET from this server
```

As part of the mentioned tutorial and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56006993/hide-cloud-functions-execution-behind-cloud-endpoints) from a Google product manager , I'm securing my function by granting ESP permission to invoke my function.

```
gcloud beta functions add-iam-policy-binding function1 --member "serviceAccount:id-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com" --role "roles/cloudfunctions.invoker" --project "project_id"
```

My `openapi-functions.yaml`

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: Cloud Endpoints + GCF
  description: Sample API on Cloud Endpoints with a Google Cloud Functions backend
  version: 1.0.0
host: HOST
x-google-endpoints:
- name: "HOST"
  allowCors: "true
schemes:
  - https
produces:
  - application/json
paths:
  /function1:
    get:
      operationId: function1
      x-google-backend:
        address: https://REGION-FUNCTIONS_PROJECT_ID.cloudfunctions.net/function1GET
      responses:
        '200':
          description: A successful response
          schema:
            type: string
```

Note that I added

```
- name: "HOST"
  allowCors: "true'
```

to my `.yaml` file because I need to access the endpoint from a static site hosted on Firebase.

Answer (score 8):

I encountered this recently. It turns out that as of January 15, 2020 new functions require authentication by default.

See [the docs here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access-iam#allowing_unauthenticated_function_invocation) for details.

The solution was to manually add the `Cloud Functions Invoker` permission to the `allUsers` user in the Cloud Functions page in the Google Cloud Console.

Comment: I did that, but my application still gets client is forbidden

Comment: That took away the 403 Forbidden error. Now I get `Error: could not handle the request` directly as content of the Trigger URL which sounds much less severe, thanks.

Comment: For my 2nd gen function, it didn't allow assigning `Cloud Functions Invoker` to `allUsers`. Instead, there is a setting in Cloud Run -> x -> Triggers -> Allow unauthenticated invocations. This helped!

Answer (score 2):

Google Cloud Functions recently (not sure how recently) added some new IAM functionality and now new functions don’t have public access by default.

To allow your function to be invoked you first have to add permissions to the function, you can see the step by step at:

https://lukestoolkit.blogspot.com/2020/06/google-cloud-functions-error-forbidden.html

Comment: You should put the whole step by step details in your answer here, instead of linking elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful. The tutorial is a bit out of date with the current UI though, so the flow was a bit off.

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons for which you are getting this error message “Your client does not have permission to get URL /… from this server” among them are:

Your internet browser history - Try deleting your history/Cache

Insufficient account permissions - Try a different account with elevated privileges

Missing SSL parameters - Try accessing the URL directly using the “curl” command

Check for malware

Answer (score 1):

While both above answers are correct, typically the thing to note is your functions deployment would have shown an error (related to the IAM policy that is being applied to the deployment), but deployed the function regardless.

In my case I was following the [Google Cloud code lab example](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-functions-go-http) when I hit the error.

I was using a service account, which had editor access to project, so I assumed I would be able to apply the `--allow-unauthenticated` policy but it turns out the project editor only gives `iam.roles.list` and `iam.roles.get` so the policy never got applied to the function (hence the above error).

To fix I  had to:

- Delete the function (only needed, if you were applying the `--allow-unauthenticated` policy as it is only applied on the first deployment of the function, and ignored in any subsequent update to functions)
- Give the service account additional IAM related roles.
- Deploy the function again

I was able to curl the endpoint successfully.